# live('click') working on desktop, but not on mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, mobile, live

I am trying to create a small secondary navigation bar that will display for mobile devices. It will eventually show and hide specific divs depending on the link clicked. I am using the color change as a test to see if everything is calling correctly. The color change works fine on a desktop browser, but not on smartphones.

After searching for advice here, I have tried "delegate" without success. I believe live() is superior for a show/hide function anyways. None of the other advice I could find seemed relevant to this situation. I have tried using the preventDefault method rather than return false, though I'm not clear on the practical differences between the two, and neither has worked.

I am a designer, not a developer, and am very new to jquery, though I am somewhat familiar with basic coding terminology and best practices.

```
$('#nav2 a').unbind("click");

$('#nav2 a').live('click',function(){
    $(this).css('color','#F00');
    return false;
});
```

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="nav2"><p><ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="smOnIssue">In This Issue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="smFeatures">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="smArchive">Archive</a></li>
</ul></p></div>
```

As I said, it is working fine on the desktop, but the mobile does nothing. I am using the most recent version of jquery. Thank you! I really appreciate whatever help any of you can give me.

Comment: In what exact browsers it doesn't work? Most modern devices with touch interfaces don't fire "click" event, because there is no mouse, but they do fire various tap events

Comment: Yes, modern touch devices do fire click events. There can be issues if there are hover events, because the first touch will fire hover and it can take an additional touch to fire the click.

Comment: I am testing in Browser that is default with Droid, and with Dolphin. A friend also tested on their Smartphone, but I don't know which browser, and it still didn't work. I have no hover events attached, not even a css color change.

Comment: I should add that other similar events on other links are working the same on all mobile browsers, and on the desktop. The working code is below.

    $('.readMore').on('click',function(){
     $(this).css('color','#F00');
    });

Answer (score 0):

> "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: regardless of deprecation, using the .live method should still work

Comment: Yes. I replaced with on(), and the same problem is still showing. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the code inside of the pageinit - which is equivalent to document.ready function http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html.  It sounds like the reason why it's not binding the click event handler is because the element is not available in the dom yet

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function(){
    $('#nav2 a').live('click',function(){
        $(this).css('color','#F00');
        return false;
    });
})
```

From the jquerymobile doc I linked above

> **Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event. This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.
>
> **Important: $(document).bind('pagecreate') vs $(document).bind('pageinit')**
>
> Prior to Beta 2 the recommendation to users wishing to manipulate jQuery Mobile enhanced page and child widget markup was to bind to the pagecreate event. In Beta 2 an internal change was made to decouple each of the widgets by binding to the pagecreate event in place of direct calls to the widget methods. As a result, users binding to the pagecreate in mobileinit would find their binding executing before the markup had been enhanced by each of the plugins. In keeping with the lifecycle of the jQuery UI Widget Factory, the initialization method is invoked after the create method, so the pageinit event provides the correct timing for post enhancement manipulation of the DOM and/or Javascript objects. In short, if you were previously using pagecreate to manipulate the enhanced markup before the page was shown, it's very likely you'll want to migrate to 'pageinit'.

Comment: I should have specified that all of my code is contained in the (document).ready(). I thought that was standard practice. Does that make a difference?

It is working on the desktop, so it has to be some difference in requirements between the mobile device and the desktop. I just haven't the least clue what that might be.

Like I said, I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: @SilverSong  I think I'm confused..Are you using jQuery mobile or just regular jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detach an event attached with `.live()` you should use `.die()`
have you tried with 'tap' instead of 'click' event ?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add onclick="" to the element you want to fire on mobile browsers.

```
<div id="nav2" onclick=""><p><ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="smOnIssue">In This Issue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="smFeatures">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="smArchive">Archive</a></li>
</ul></p></div>
```